# Highchart Semi Circle With Gauge Chart. Shrink pie chart and move gauge up

Tags: highcharts

I have a jsfiddle with a semi circle and gauge chart. I shrunk the pie chart, and the gauge stayed in the middle of the pie chart. I want to move the arrow up to the bottom of the pie chart.

See the attached image for what I want.

[image]

See the fiddle for what I have:
http://jsfiddle.net/mschreiberjdi/xumhy0zL/

```
enter code here
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't remember exactly which changes I made but after fiddling around with it, I came up with what you're looking for.

http://jsfiddle.net/467pyero/

[image]

You'll need to play with the settings for the gray triangle to get it how you had it before but that should be pretty easy.

Basically what I did is moved everything down to the bottom of the canvas.  The y-center inner dial is 95% to the bottom and its size is set at 80% which makes it fit perfectly inside the outer dial.  To see it clearer, you can set its `backgroundColor` to `'silver'` instead of `null`.

```
$(function() {
  $('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
      renderTo: 'container',
      plotBackgroundColor: null,
      plotBackgroundImage: null,
      plotBorderWidth: 0,
      plotShadow: false
    },
    title: {
      text: '40%<br>Probability Of <br>Success',
      align: 'center',
      verticalAlign: 'bottom',
      y: -70
    },
    tooltip: {
      pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
    },
    pane: {
      center: ['50%', '95%'],
      size: '80%',
      startAngle: -90,
      endAngle: 90,
      background: {
        borderWidth: 0,
        backgroundColor: null,
        innerRadius: '90%',
        outerRadius: '100%',
        shape: 'arc'
      }
    },
    yAxis: [{
      lineWidth: 0,
      min: 0,
      max: 90,
      minorTickLength: 0,
      tickLength: 0,
      tickWidth: 0,
      labels: {
        enabled: false
      },
      title: {
        text: '', //'<div class="gaugeFooter">46% Rate</div>',
        useHTML: true,
        y: 80
      },
      pane: 0,

    }],
    plotOptions: {
      pie: {
        dataLabels: {
          enabled: true,
          distance: 0,
          style: {
            fontWeight: 'bold',
            color: 'white',
            textShadow: '0px 1px 2px black'
          }
        },
        startAngle: -90,
        endAngle: 90,
        center: ['50%', '100%']
      },
      gauge: {
        dataLabels: {
          enabled: false
        },
        pivot: {
          radius: 125,
          borderWidth: 2,
          borderColor: 'transparent',
          backgroundColor: 'white'
        },
        dial: {
          radius: '100%',
          backgroundColor: 'gray',
          borderColor: 'gray',
          baseWidth: 140,
          topWidth: 1,
          baseLength: '5%', // of radius
          rearLength: '5%'
        }
      }
    },

    series: [{
      type: 'pie',
      name: 'Browser share',
      innerSize: '85%',
      data: [
        ['', 25],
        ['', 25],
        ['', 25]
      ]
    }, {
      type: 'gauge',
      data: [40],
      dial: {
        rearLength: 0
      }
    }],
  });
});
```

Comment: How would I style the title and make Probability Of Success smaller text?

Comment: Check the API docs for title styling: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#title.style